# jquery, prevent onclick=window.location on parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a table with data such as this:

```
<table>
 <tr onclick="window.location='download.php?id=1'">
  <td>Program 1<br/>Short Description 1 (<a onclick="$.popup.show('Install Instructions', 'Instructions pulled from DB here')">Instructions</a>)</td>
  <td>Added by user and date/time here<td>
  <td>Filesize here<td>
  <td><a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a> - <a href="delete.php?id=1">Delete</a><td>
 </tr>
 (repeat TRs for more programs pulled from DB)
</table>
```

The problem I'm having is that when you click the (Instructions) link, it should popup a window with the instructions. It does do it, but it also fires the TR's onclick. So I get the popup for a split second then it goes to download.php.

Is there someway I can prevent it from firing the TR's onclick? Preferably using jquery, but I don't mind a plain javascript solutions either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to stop [propagation of events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), using event.cancelBubble (for IE) or event.stopPropagation() (for everyone else).  The [solution given from quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9) (which I've used before) is to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var instructions = function(e) {
    // Get the correct event in a cross-browser manner, then stop bubbling/propagation.
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    // Do what you want now
    $.popup.show('Install Instructions', 'Instructions pulled from DB here');
}
</script>
```

Then your script would call it:

```
<td>Program 1<br/>Short Description 1 (<a onclick="instructions(event)">Instructions</a>)</td>
```

(Of course, you could put this all inline, but that's a bloody mess.)

You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute) illuminating.

Comment: I'm surprised it lasted 16 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

stopPropogation is the one you want.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
onclick="false"
```

and add events using event model level 2 (attachEvent in ie or addEventListener in other browsers).
You can also you jquery bind ('click') if you use jquery.