# how do I link a div and then link within the div

Tags: html

I have a requirement to link the whole div to a certain url. Within the div is content and in the content there needs to be a link. What's the best way to do this? So lets say I have the following code:

```
<div class="pet_container" onClick="window.location.href='some.html'">
<div class="pet_bullets_text">
<ul>
<li id="links">Retailer locator on <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com" target="_blank"><u>somewebsite.com</u></a> brings customers into your store</li>
</ul>                       
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this works. Because, the click event when it is fired on the `<a>` tag, it has more priority.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want. How does the code above NOT do what you want?

Comment: The "best" way is subjective. What you have is fine.

Comment: If I click on my href in the <li> tag the onClick event fires too, I don't want that to happen. How do I control/separate these?   Sorry for not being more clear on this.

Comment: I found my solution after more in-depth researching on this site:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979257/execute-href-of-an-anchor-but-not-onclick-of-underlying-div?lq=1