# restrict event propagation in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

How can I prevent an event from bubbling up to parent in javascript?

Eg.

```
<tr id="my_tr" onclick="javascript:my_tr_click();">
   <td>
      <a id="my_atag" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:my_a_click();">Delete</a>
   <td>
</tr>
```

When I click on "Delete" anchor tag, first the **my_a_click()** function gets called, and then the parent tr onclick function - **my_tr_click()** - gets called. This, I believe, is called event propagation.

How can I stop that **my_tr_click()** function from getting called when I click on the child anchor tag?

Please help me out..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute/387843#387843) this is most likely what you want to do to handle your inline `onclick()`.

```
function my_a_click(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And adjust your markup:

```
<a id="my_atag" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="var event = arguments[0] || window.event; my_a_click(event);">Delete</a>
```

[**Working example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/jPFwh/6/)

tested in chrome, firefox 4 and IE9.

With all that being said, if jQuery is an option it would make things *a lot* easier.

```
$("#my_atag").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

and

```
<a id="my_atag" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
```

Comment: the example you gave works well on Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox..it calls the tr onclick function there..

Comment: Checked and works perfectly....thanks a ton, you are The Savior......God Bless You...

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be interested in http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

```
something.onclick = function (e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for replying.. This solution doesn't seem to be working well for Firefox..