# Prevent event propagation using Google Closure Library

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, google-closure, google-closure-library

Using **Google Closure Library**:

How can I handle clicking of an `element` for example a `div` but prevent firing the `event handler` when the user clicks the child elements of that element.

For example in the following code I want to fire the `event handler` when user click `div1` but when he/she clicks 'span1' I want another `event handler` to be called without firing the handler of `div1`.

```
<div style="width: 400px" id="div1">
 <span id="span1">click me to reload</span>
 click here to Toggle accordion
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

**JS Code:**

```
/**** accordion ***/
var panels = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('newsColumnHeader', goog.dom.getElement('accordionContainer'));

var anims  = {};
var open   = null;

goog.array.forEach(panels, function(pane){
  var animation = new goog.ui.AnimatedZippy(pane, goog.dom.getNextElementSibling(pane));
  goog.events.listen(animation, goog.ui.Zippy.Events.TOGGLE, zippyToggle);
  anims[goog.getUid(animation)] = animation;
});

function zippyToggle(event) {      
  var uid = goog.getUid(event.target);                  
  // simple logic - only one open panel in one time
  if (event.expanded && uid != open) {
    if (open) {
      anims[open].setExpanded(false);
    }
    open = uid;
  }
}
/******************/           

var refreshVarzesh3 = goog.dom.getElement("btnRefreshVarzesh3");
if (refreshVarzesh3 != null) {
  goog.events.listen(refreshVarzesh3, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function(event) {
    /*doing something but not toggling accordion pane*/
  });
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
  <body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div id="toolbar">          
      <img src="css/img/contact.png" alt="تماس، پیشنهاد، گزارش خطا" title="تماس، پیشنهاد، گزارش خطا"/>          
    </div>
    <img src="css/img/football_news.gif" alt="آخرین اخبار فوتبال"/>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionContainer">
        <div class="newsColumnHeader">
          <div class="buttons">
            <img id="btnRefreshVarzesh3" src="css/img/refresh.png" alt="به روز رسانی" title="به روز رسانی"/>                
          </div>
          <%=lbls.getString("Varzesh3News")%>
        </div>
        <div class="newsList" id="varzesh3NewsContainer"></div>
        <div class="newsColumnHeader"><%=lbls.getString("PersepolisNews")%></div>
        <div class="newsList" id="persepolisNewsContainer"></div>
        <div class="newsColumnHeader"><%=lbls.getString("EsteghlalNews")%></div>
        <div class="newsList" id="esteghlalNewsContainer"></div>
        <div class="newsColumnHeader"><%=lbls.getString("NavadNews")%></div>
        <div class="newsList" id="navadNewsContainer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+propagation+javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for **pure javascript** developers the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779319/restrict-event-propagation-in-javascript) but if you use **Google Closure Library** the following code is enough:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 4):

in the event handler of that click you have to use preventDefault()

for example:

```
document.getElementById('div1').onclick = function (event) {
   //your code
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for Reference All events in Google Closure are derived from [goog.events.Event](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_events_Event.html)

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_events_Event.html

For Example : [goog.events.BrowserEvents](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_events_BrowserEvent.html)

So **first** one is `stopPropagation`

```
 this.getHandler().listen(element ,goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

**Second** one is `goog.events.Event.stopPropagation`  is a static method
which in turn calls above method

```
goog.events.Event.stopPropagation = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Edit :
Please do read - [Dangers of Event Propagation](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)