# How to prevent javascript bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am talking about Jquery. Say, I have a button, I clicked it and a new div is dynamically created. I clicked again and another div is created. This way I created 3 div.

Each of the newly created div also dynamically creates a button, clicking which I want to get alert('something')

**Problem** is that, when I click button of 1st div(newly created div) I get the alert 3 times, When I click button of  2nd div(newly created div), I get alert 2 times. For every one click I want to get alert **only once**. But I am facing Javascript bubbling*

My Javascript and HTML codes:

```js
$("#btn11").click(function(){
    var nw="<div class='product_input'><input type='text'/><br/>";
    nw+="<button type='button' class='btn12'>Add category</button>";
    nw+="</div>";
    $("#apnd1").append(nw);

    $(".btn12").click(function(){
      alert("jhfj");
    });
  });
```

```html
<div id="apnd1"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn11">Add product</button>
```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Don't bind every time...

Comment: Should I unbind 1st click event? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [restrict event propagation in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779319/restrict-event-propagation-in-javascript)

Comment: @David, I searched similar problems, but didnt get, so asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont bind the events inside another evens. You can bind it outside. Since it is dynamically created, you need to use delegate to bind the events. Then you will not get multiple alerts

```
$("#btn11").click(function() {
    var nw = "<div class='product_input'><input type='text'/><br/>";
    nw += "<button type='button' class='btn12'>Add category</button>";
    nw += "</div>";
    $("#apnd1").append(nw);
});
$("#apnd1").on("click", ".btn12", function() {
    alert("jhfj");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxtu6qm3/7/)

Comment: voted up for having read the question and having defined a proper selector ("#apnd1").

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the same, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/79gv3v3w/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn11").click(function(){
            var nw="<div class='product_input'><input type='text'/><br/>";
            nw+="<button type='button' class='btn12'>Add category</button>";
            nw+="</div>";
            $("#apnd1").append(nw);            
        });
    $(document).on('click', ".btn12", function(){
                alert("jhfj");
            });
});
```