# How to stop propagation of page after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. And an text box inside it. I wrote validation for onchange event to the text xox and same validation at the time of submission. When I change that value and hit enter first it checks the onChange validation and again onsubmit validation. How can I stop after the onChange validation. 
I used event.stopPropagation , window.event.cancelBubble = true but it din't worked? 
Ant ideas or suggestion how to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
return false;
```

?

Comment: wow it works, I feel so stupid. I tried everything except this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute/387750#387750)

Answer (score 0):

use this code to stop after onchange:

`yourValidationScript()` must return boolean `true` or `flase`

```
onchange="return yourValidationScript(); submit()"
```

if yourValidationScript returned false, the script will stop, else it will submit..