# Submitting a form does not work for IE 9

Tags: jsp

It works for Firefox and Chrome though
Not very sure what is the reason.
Using jsp in apache tomcat.

form code is as below

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="zzz.jsp?yy=submit">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Submitconfirm()" />
    </p>
</form>
```

javascript of Submitconfirm

```
function Submitconfirm() {
    var a = document.getElementById("form1");

    if (confirm()) {
        a.submit();
    }
}

function confirm() {
    return confirm('Are you sure these details are correct?');
}
```

jsp does not have postback function so I had to resort to this,on submit will execute javascript to send the form.

Comment: updated the function, I get a Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage error everytime I run on IE 9

Comment: not very sure it has something to do with this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577542/ie9-double-form-submit-issue

Comment: You have a `</p>` tag in the form that is not balanced.

Comment: I don't think it is related to that SO question - it had a `type="submit"` on the same element that had the `onClick`. Your button is `type="button"` so it should not submit the form on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your button to something else as its causing a clash with the JS `.submit()` function. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834197/249327) for more details. E.g.

```
<input type="button" name="submitButton" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Submitconfirm()" />
```