# retain links functionality inside a div that has an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a `div` that has an `onclick` that hides the `div`.

If I have a link inside the `div`, the link does not work, because the `onclick` steals the click.

The desired result: if a click is made anywhere inside the div BUT the link, that the div gets hidden. If a click is made ON the link, then I want the link to open in a _blank window, and the div to remain visible.

Is there a way to deal with this with javascript?

Comment: Essentially the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVGJQ/6/)

Inside the click handler for the link, you'll want to call [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation), or set e.cancelBubble to true—whichever your browser prefers.  This will prevent the event from bubbling to your div.

```
document.getElementById("thelink").onclick = function (e) {
    window.open();
    if (e.stopPropogation)
        e.stopPropogation();
    if (e.cancelBubble != null)
        e.cancelBubble = true;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('yourlinksid').onclick = function(e){

   // ... pop your window ...

   /* the following prevents the event from "bubbling up"
      to the div's event handler */
   if(!e.stopPropagation) {
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      return;
   }

   e.stopPropagation();    
};
```

**Verification:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kSTNT/4/

Comment: This JS/jQuery mash won't work. `click()` doesn't exist in the `getElementById()` context.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the links, the easiest way is to add onclick="event.stopPropagation();" (or whatever the cross-browser version of that is) to each link, which stops the div from seeing the event without preventing the default effect of the link from taking place.

Alternatively, if the links only contain text, then you can check the tag name of the event's target in the div's click event to see whether it is a link, but if you have something more complex then you need to walk the dom tree from the event target to the div to verify that no link exists.