# Chaining :not selector in jquery.on

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a table of rows that are dynamically managed via listjs.  I have made these rows clickable to open a Bootstrap Modal based on a data attribute (data-modal).  This all works fine except for when a link appears in the columns of the rows.  Both the anchor is firing and the modal is opening.

To prevent this, I used the following code, which worked on initially loaded elements:

```
$("[data-modal]").on("click", "a:not(.open-disabled)", function(e) {//open modal code}
```

But as expected, this doesn't bind to dynamically injected rows or divs.

So I changed my code to try binding to $(document) instead, but I can't get the :not selector to chain properly -- the selectors aren't being properly identified and the modal does not open.

Here is what I changed my code to:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-modal], a:not(.open-disabled)", function(e) {}
```

Questions:
A. How do I chain selectors in the above to prevent the modal from opening if there is an anchor child element that is being clicked.

B. Is there a better method of preventing the modal from opening?

Comment: I tried the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045431/jquery-filtering-has-not -- it works partially, but now the entire row that an anchor tag is present on is not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by implementing the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696420/2659318

Here is the resulting code:

```
  $(document).on("click", "[data-modal]", function() {
    $(this).modal();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "a.open-disabled", function(e) {
    if (!e.stopPropagation) {
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      return;
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-modal] > a:not(.open-disabled)", function(e) {}
                         //-----------^ use child selector here
```