# Why can't I stop this js click event propogation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to override a click handler by intercepting the event in an inline handler and stopping propagation (propogation disabling code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108218/165673)).

The following code not only doesn't stop the propagation, it's not even firing the inline handler. I can't tell what's wrong.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trKN4/3/

**HTML:**

```
<a onclick='stopIt(event);'>do it</a>​
```

**JS:**

```
function disableEventPropagation(event)
{
   if (event.stopPropagation){
       event.stopPropagation();
   }
   else if(window.event){
      window.event.cancelBubble=true;
   }
}

function stopIt(event) {
    disableEventPropagation(event);
    alert('dont do it');
}


$(function() {

    $('a').click(function(e){
        alert('im doing it');
    });                   

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not firing the inline function because jsFiddle is wrapping all your code in an `onload` handler, taking it out of the reachable scope of the handler.

Choose a `no wrap` option from the menu on the left.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/trKN4/4/

[image]

Comment: @Yarin: It does stop propagation. You've placed both handlers on the same element, so neither handler is a *result* of propagation. Put the jQuery handler on the `'body'`, and you'll see it work. http://jsfiddle.net/trKN4/12/

Comment: Got it, but now im confused- What's the proper way to undo/prevent a non-inline handler from receiving the event?

Comment: @Yarin: Depends on the situation, but if you don't control the non-inline handler, I don't know that it's possible.

Comment: It is, just figured out- stopImmediatePropogation()- see http://jsfiddle.net/trKN4/13/ (Need to figure out solution for the cancelBubble part..)

Comment: @Yarin: Yeah, I'm guessing browser support will be the tough part.

Comment: OK, aparently  *jquery* stopPropogation/stopImmediatePropogation *does* work cross browser, so this plus your answer make a solution. Thanks

Comment: @Yarin: Yes, jQuery's does. I don't think it'll work on native `event` objects in all browsers, but maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, glad you got it working.