# Onclick Event Not Working, Onmouse Working Though

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have build an instant search with AJAX, It is like when you start typing result appears, then if you click anywhere on the body result disappear, onmouse over at input field result re appear. when clicked inside input field result disappers.

I want this result to stays open after onmouse event when clicked in input field. for that i have added a click event, but it is not working.

Please see the codes and suggest any possible way to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("search-result").style.border = "0px";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("search-result").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
                document.getElementById("search-result").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseover = function() {
                    show_box()
                };
                document.getElementById("search-input").onclick = function() {
                    show_box()
                };
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "instant-search.php?keyword=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function close_box() {
        fadeOut();
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display = "none";

    }

    function show_box() {
        setOpacity(0);
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display = "block";
        fadeIn();
    }
    document.onclick = function() {
        close_box()
    };

    function setOpacity(value) {
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
    }

    function fadeIn() {
        for (var i = 20; i <= 100; i++)
        setTimeout('setOpacity(' + (i / 5) + ')', 5 * i);
    }

    function fadeOut() {
        for (var i = 20; i <= 100; i++)
        setTimeout('setOpacity(' + (5 - i / 5) + ')', 5 * i);
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" onkeydown="showResult(this.value)"    autocomplete="off" />
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

Comment: where is `onclick` event in your html?

Comment: its in javascript, do i need it in html too.

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka: not in html, but present in javascript.

Comment: I think The result is invisible because of the `setOpacity(0)`

Comment: try giving `setOpacity(10)` instead

Comment: Are you sure it ever arrives at document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseover = function() {
                    show_box()
                };
Add an alert or console.log() or something to check.

Comment: you need `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` in your document.getElementById("search-input").onclick function

Comment: @ thinklinux also can you tell me how to stop onmouse event again and again as it shows blinking when mouse over again.

Comment: @ thinklinux {e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()} working in firefox not working in internet explorer

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: @TallboY use mouseenter and mouseleave events ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so into jQuery that I forgot there is a difference on IE.

```
if(!e) {
  e = window.event;
}

if(e.stopPropagation && e.preventDefault) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
} else {
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: It now worked perfectly. Thanks, also can you tell me how to stop on-mouse event occurring again so that it will not show blinking of fading effect on mouse-over again.

Comment: I commented about that in your question above

Comment: that didnt help still blinking on onmouseenter or onmouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

try this?
`<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" onclick="showResult(this.value)" autocomplete="off" />`
or to test if onclick works

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" onclick="alert('replace this with your function you want to call');"    autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: yes this is working but i got to do it in javascript as i have to do it for onclick and onkeyup this way which will result in two query, while in javascript i just have to show and hide the query result.

Comment: i tried @thinklinux method it is working in all browser but not in Internet explorer. do you have any workaround for that.