# Conflicting Events in Nested HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have nested event listeners. Exactly they are

```
<tr onclick="function1();">
<td>....</td>
<td onclick="function2();">....</td>
</tr>
```

When Second Cell is clicked, only function2() should be called and not function1(). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: if you are using a function on td, i think there is no use of tr cause tr is departed by one or many table datas(tds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event can be stopped using [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

```
function(e) {
   var event = e || window.event;
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

See the answer here for more discussion: [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: Great! This worked. I had already tried return false. I could not make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass event object in the function and call stopPropagation to stop event propogation.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Dz5pu/1/)**

```
<tr onclick="return function1(e);">
  <td>First Td....</td>
 <td onclick="return function2();">second td....</td>
</tr>

function function2(e)
{
  //your statements.
   alert("function2");
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: does anyone understand why `return false` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Adil Yes, adding event.stopPropagation solved the problem.
I also don't get why return false did not work.

Comment: That works for jquery and I use that often. jquery has provided custom functionality with return.