# Outer event raise than inner event

Tags: javascript, html-table

I created the following html:

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td onclick="window.location.href = 'Add.html'">
                1
                <div onclick="window.location.href = 'Update.html'">
                    Update me
                </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

When I click td, it redirect `Add.html`. It is OK. But when I click div, it also redirect to `Add.html` page. I would like to redirect to `Update.html` page.

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/6DGDR/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HG83V/3/)**

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td onclick="loadUrl(event,'add.html')">
                Add me
                <div onclick="loadUrl(event,'update.html')">
                    Update me
                </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loadUrl(ev,url)
{
    var e = ev || window.event;
    alert(url);

    // do whatever you want


    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```