# How to call a function within a function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function btn1(){
alert('hello')
}
function btn2(){
alert('anchor') 
}
```

I want to call the function btn1 and function btn2 separate on clicking the div. As it is shown below.

```
<div onclick="btn2()" style="position:relative">
<div style="width:50%; float:left; height:50px; background:#ddd">
</div>
<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="btn1()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi guys i want to call the function separately, suppose I click on entire div it should call the function btn2 and if I click on the input button it should call the function btn1.

Comment: it's exactly how you have it there.  are you experiencing difficulty with it?

Comment: Also make sure the JavaScript code is in a script tag. :)

Comment: separate or one of the functions together with the other as in function btn2(){
alert('anchor') btn1()
}

Comment: Just a friendly advice, is not necessary but it's good practice, use ";" at the end of the line of the alerts

Comment: It is in script tag. If i clicking on the input button then btn2 function is also happening. I want to call only btn1 function on clicking the input button.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Answer (score 3):

If I am getting this right you are probably experiencing bubbling. You might want to read about bubbling and event propagation as it will probably be clearer than what I can try to explain. But to solve your issue you want to take a look at jquery's

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 0):

The Click Event of the button bubbles his way up to the div. Take a look here how to prevent this:

[How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

I recommend you use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) in favor of inline event handler.