# Javascript WYSIWYG removeEventListener then bring it back

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg

I am creating a weird WYSIWYG from scratch using pure JS as an exercise. Here is my code thus far:

```
<style> 
    body {
        height: 200px;
        background: white;
    }

    .title1 {
        height: 12px; 
        width: 100px;
        background: white;
        position: relative;

    }
</style>    
<script>
newTitle1 = function() {
    var title1 = document.createElement("div")
    title1.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true")
    title1.innerHTML = "whatever";
    title1.className = "title1";
    title1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        removeEventListener("click", newTitle1);
    })

    title1.style.left = (event.pageX -4) + "px";
    title1.style.top = (event.pageY -4 ) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(title1)

}   

addEventListener("click", newTitle1)    
</script>
```

My question is specifically about

```
title1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        removeEventListener("click", newTitle1);
    })
```

I want `removeEventListener` to work while I click into the div that it just created. BUT, when I click outside of the div, I want `newTitle1` to work.

**Bottomline:** I want `newTitle1` listener to work outside of the div it just created, and not to work inside the div it creates. Any ideas how to make this happen? Here is a fiddle of my code to test if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/nirchernia/v3cLwb82/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to stop the event propagating. Solution shamelessly stolen from [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute).

```
newTitle1 = function() {
var title1 = document.createElement("div")
title1.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true")
title1.innerHTML = "whatever";
title1.className = "title1";
title1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    window.event.cancelBubble = true
})

title1.style.left = (event.pageX -4) + "px";
title1.style.top = (event.pageY -4 ) + "px";
document.body.appendChild(title1)
```

}

addEventListener("click", newTitle1)

/edit: And I think you want your `.title1` CSS to have `position:absolute;` too :)