# HTML prevents click event on an inner div

Tags: html

I tried to use an event listener with HTML:

```
<div style="width: 200px;height: 200px" id="outerDiv" onClick="alert(1)">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="width: 200px;height: 200px">no click</div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that clicking in a div (id=innerDiv) doesn't alert 1? I want it so that clicking only the outer div gives an alert.

Comment: Consider adding 'css' and 'javascript' tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent propagation like this on the `innerDiv` so it will only fire for the `outerDiv`:

```
 onClick="event.stopPropagation()"
```

Also see [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: I believe OP wants only the `outerDiv` to `alert(1)`, not the `innerDiv`

Comment: I think putting `onClick="alert(1)"` on the `outerDiv` and `onClick="event.stopPropagation()"` on the `innerDiv` will do so.

Comment: I believe it will but your wording says _so it will not fire for the `outerDiv`_ but this is what the OP wants. [Your code is correct](http://jsfiddle.net/8qb0nzco/), but I think the wording is not.