# How to stop event propagation on onclick event in html attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html element with an onclick attribute and I need to prevent that event from bubbling up. I tried doing this:

```
<div onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
```

and this:

```
<div onclick="(function(event){event.stopPropagation();})();)">
```

But neither works. I absolutely need to do this in the html onclick attribute since this div is part of a Razor partial view and the script is set on the ViewData dictionary. How do I call event.stopPropagation() on the html onclick attribute?

Edit: the error in this case is that event is null. So for some reason, I can´t access the event like this.

Comment: I don't know Razor, or the ViewData dictionary; but can you not link to a function to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: event.stopPropagation(); should be working. Have you tried not making it an inline onclick event?

MDN Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: You have an error in your second code: there is an unmatched close parenthesis. Also, why did you make it in a self-invoking function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method of `Event`. There is a mistake in your second code snippet where you do not pass `event` to the anonymous function. Fixed code:

`<div onclick="(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); })(event)">`

Comment: @LambdaNinja Fixed

Comment: It turns out I didn´t pass the event! Thanks!

Comment: @Magnus: You say your first example doesn't work either. If that doesn't work, wrapping an immediately invoked function around it isn't going to change anything. The wrapping function is entirely pointless here.

Comment: @squint This is true -- and I am actually quite intrigued as to how the anonymous function works and the direct reference to `event` does not.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick inline function is implemented as:

```
function(event) {
}
```

So you can just use the 'event' variable.

```
<div onclick='event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault()'>
```

There is no need to implement inline functions. Your first example should work if you add the event.preventDefault().