# jquery .click() function on specific attribute, returns multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with jquery and the .click() function, when clicking on a `<li data-link-url="...">` element, that shares the **data-link-url** attribute.

This is my HTML structure:

```html
<nav class="fullListHover">
  <ul>
    <li class="oneHub">
      <a href="... /suppliers/technology.html"></a>
      <ul>
        <li data-link-url="... /templateA.html">
          <ul>
            <li data-link-url="... /templateB.html"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>       
</nav>
```

And this is my jquery click() function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("[data-link-url]").click(function(){
      window.location.href=$(this).attr("data-link-url")
  });
</script>
```

When I click on the **li-tag** with **".../templateB.html"** I get redirected to **".../templateA.html"**.
So I debugged the whole thing and logged the **$(this)** variable. When I clicked on **".../templateB.html"** the output was:

```
.../templateB.html
.../templateA.html
```

It seems like, the .click() function runs a second time.

How can I select just the templateB or prevent the click function to run a second time ?

P.S.: I hope my question is understandable. English isn't my primary language.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but there are likely others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: click events bubble.

Comment: I must have looked for the wrong keywords, because I didn't find any suitable answer for my problem. Thank you though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you have nested `li` elements with the `data-link-url` attribute, hence the click handler is invoked once for each element in the hierarchy as the event bubbles up the DOM. To fix this, call `stopPropagation()` in the event handler:

```
$("[data-link-url]").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location.href = $(this).data('link-url');
});
```

Comment: Sample fiddle with `stopPropagation` - remove the line to see the event bubble: https://jsfiddle.net/7wto6hrh/

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why using .data() instead of .attr() ? Is it because of IE problems with .attr() ?

Comment: In most cases it's faster as it's using jQuery's internal cache instead of accessing the DOM.