# disable onclick only on one element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a function to display my wordpress search form, and to hide it. The problem is that I want all the container to be clickable to display/hide, but when I click the text input of my search form it hide it. Is it possible to not trigger the onclick event when I click on the input ?

Here is my architecture :

```
<li onclick="search_form(this)">
  <img src="#" >
  <div>
      <form role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="/">
          <div>
              <input type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" required="" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have something like that https://puu.sh/t3tiN/8655c07973.png (picture of my li)

Thank you

Edit : Someone asked me for the function, didn't want to add it because it's just css :

```
function search_form() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1041) {
      var display = $('#mobile_search_form').css('display');
            if (display == "none") {
                  /* many css animate */

            } else if (display == "inline-block") {
                  /* many css animate */
            }
    }else if ($(window).width() < 1041) {
      window.location.href = "#"
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#result_number').css('display',"none");
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: _I have a function_ Share its code

Comment: the code is too long, and full of css animate, but I can still share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). I think this is exactely what you want to do:

```
<li id="myLi">
  <img src="#" >
  <div>
      <form role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="/">
          <div>
              <input type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" required="" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#myLi").click(search_form($(this));
$("#s").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: You're right it's exactly what I couldn't find. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of inline script:

```
<li onclick="search_form(this)">
  <img src="#" >
  <div>
      <form role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="/">
          <div>
              <input onclick="event.stopPropagation()" type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" required="" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Credit: I got the answer from [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: I can't do that, it's a form generated by wordpress.