# How to prevent Accordion Panel from collapsing when I use button added to header?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have problem with Accordion Panel. I have Accordion similar to this:

```
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:tab title="tabTitle">
        <f:facet name="title">
            <!-- problematic button -->
            <p:commandButton value="button"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:PanelGrid>
            <p>Accordion content</p>
        </h:panelGrdi>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

The problem is - when I click the button, whole Accordion Tab will collapse.

My question is: How to prevent Accordion from collapsing on button click? At the same time I would like Accordion to collapse when I click on header but outside the button.

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3 and JSF 2.2.11

Comment: This is a bit complicated. Problem here is that accordion has a click event binded to it and the button which is inside the accordion, inherits this binding the solution would be trick. I see two options here, 1-you create a layer outside the accordion , place the button on it and programaticaly position it over the accordion. 2- Change the code to not propagate the click event on the button.

Comment: do you want to make it open even if you click on another element ???

Comment: @JorgeCampos - do you know maybe how can I achieve the effect of not propagating click event?

Comment: @YagamiLight - When I click on the button I **don't** want accordion to open or close. But when I click on accordion header (outside button) I would like accordion to behave regular way

Comment: anh how it be behave regular way  post an example (image) sure it will help

Comment: As I said you will have to change the code to not propagate the event. See it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: @JorgeCampos - thanks. I used `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"` and now everything is working like I wanted to. Thank you very much

Comment: Great to know that you were able to solve your problem. You should add this as an answer it may help others! Don't forget to mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I will, thanks. And once again thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was suggested by @JorgeCampos - we can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in order to prevent event to "bubble" from button to accordion. Usage for code posted in question will looks like this:

```
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:tab title="tabTitle">
        <f:facet name="title">
            <p:commandButton value="button" onclick="event.stopPropagation();"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:PanelGrid>
            <p>Accordion content</p>
        </h:panelGrdi>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

We can of course use other events to do something else, or use `actionListener` to call method from ManagedBean, use `update`. For example

```
<p:commandButton
    value="button"
    onclick="event.stopPropagation();"
    oncomplete="PF('someDialog').show();" <!-- open dialog by js -->
    actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod}" <!-- call java method -->
    update="someComponent" <!-- update component -->
/>
```

Stoping event propagation will not interfere

Answer (score 0):

unbind all the events of your headers and then bind them again calling the `init` method of your component.

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="myAccordion">
  <p:tab title="tabTitle">
    <f:facet name="title">
        <!-- problematic button -->
        <p:commandButton value="button"
          onclick="PF('myAccordion').jq.find('.ui-accordion-header').unbind()" 
          oncomplete= "PF('myAccordion').init(PF('myAccordion').cfg)"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:PanelGrid>
        <p>Accordion content</p>
    </h:panelGrdi>
  </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, I've tested it and it works, but I found (according on comments below question post) much simpler solution using `event.stopPropagation()` in `onclick` action