# `stopPropagation` not working properly if bound using `onclick`

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, stoppropagation

I have the following `span` on a page with several click event handlers:

```
<span class="abc">xyz</span>
```

Now I need to stop bubbling up of its click event. It can be achieved in two ways:

1. Add `stopPropagation` in one of the click handlers: (**Child-2 in fiddle**)

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".abc", function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```

   All the click handlers of the span are being called in this case and none of the parent handlers are being called which is ideal behavior.
2. Add an `onclick` property like following:(**Child-1 in fiddle**)

   ```
   <span class="abc" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">xyz</span>
   ```

   In this case, none of the click handlers are being called (neither child span nor parent).

Can someone please explain why the click handlers of child span are not being called in second case?

**Fiddle:**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".abc", function (e) {
    alert("child click!");
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", "#parent", function () {
    alert("parent click!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parent">
  <span class="abc" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Child-1!</span>
  <br />
  <span class="abc">Child-2!</span>
</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: Those links say to do what the OP says isn't working, so they don't really help here.

Comment: adding the fiddle of the problem

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not seeing a click when you use the `onclick` attribute because the click never reaches `document` — because you stopped propagation.

You're using *event delegation*:

```
$(document).on("click", ".abc", function (e) {
// ---------------------^^^^^^^
    alert("child click!");
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", "#parent", function () {
// ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^
    alert("parent click!");
});
```

That means you're really hooking the handler on `document`. If the click never bubbles to document, jQuery can't fire your delegated handlers.