# Edit row on treeTable primefaces by pressing enter and without firing commandButton submit event

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to accept an editRow event on a Primefaces TreeTable by pressing the ENTER key. But at the time of doing so, `<p:commandButton/>` catches the event.

I tried in an `<h:outputScript/>` jQuery:

```
        $('tmt-library-tree').keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.which == '13') {
                event.preventDefault();
            } 
        });
```

But it affects the entire TreeTable. I also tried selectors in the form of:

```
$("#screens\\:form\\:libraryGroupTreeTable\\:addGlobal").keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.which == '13') {
                event.preventDefault();
            } 
        });
```

Taken from the Inspect window in Chrome Developer Tools and making sure it exists.

This is the Primefaces TreeTable

```
<p:treeTable id="libraryGroupTreeTable" styleClass="library-tree" 
                 var="dummy" nodeVar="hltsOrHltsfOrLg" value="#{libraryTree}" emptyMessage=""
                 selectionMode="single" editable="#{editable}" scrollable="true">
```

and added an `<p:ajax>` to handle rowEdit

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{libraryTree.onRowEdit}" onstart="vres.onAjax(cfg, '#{libraryTree.gid}');" update="libraryGroupTreeTable"/>
```

Finally, here's my `<p:outputPanel>`

```
<p:outputPanel id="namePanel" style="display: inline-flex;">
            <span class="tree-node-icons #{hltsOrHltsfOrLg.css}"/>
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
              <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{hltsOrHltsfOrLg.name}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{hltsOrHltsfOrLg.name}"/></f:facet>
              </p:cellEditor>
            </div>
 </p:outputPanel>
```

> I need the ENTER Key to do what the `<p: ajax/>` tag is doing at
>   the moment of editing the cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: I need to do the actions from ```<p: ajax/> ```. But in the key ENTER event.