# get the button click event without the canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can i have 2 different click events for the button and the ListItem?
I'm **mostly interested in the button click event without the ListItem event.**

[CodeSandobox DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx810vjool)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

function App() {
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("button click");
  };
  const handleListItemClick = () => {
    console.log("list click");
  };
  return (
    <ListItem button onClick={() => handleListItemClick()}>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}>
        get only the button click
      </button>
      <ListItemText primary="without the ListItem click event..." />
    </ListItem>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: what output you want

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: I want the button click event to fire without the ListItem event to fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

function App() {
  const handleButtonClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("button click");
  };
  const handleListItemClick = () => {
    console.log("list click");
  };
  return (
    <ListItem button onClick={() => handleListItemClick()}>
      <button onClick={e => handleButtonClick(e)}>
        get only the button click
      </button>
      <ListItemText primary="without the ListItem click event..." />
    </ListItem>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```