# how to prevent clicking on tr while clicking button inside td of same tr

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the table row I have click event like `onclick="trDetailsModal(this, 'id')"` and I am showing details in the modal. So inside the tr I have also two buttons under actions td, those buttons are also having onclick event like `onclick="deleteRecord('id')"`;

I am able to see details in a modal by clicking on tr.

Now the problem is when I click one of the buttons the tr `onclick` also getting triggered and showing details also in model.

So how to stop tr `onclick` while clicking one of those buttons.

**Code:**

```
$content .= '<tr class="trClass" onclick="trDetail(this, '.$val->id.');">';
$content .= '<td>some value</td>';
$content .= '<td><button onclick="deleteRecord('.$val->id.')"></td>';
$content .= '</tr>';

function deleteRecord(id){

  $(".trClass").off("click");
  $("#myModal").hide();

}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's usually accomplished by calling [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the click event of the button, which prevents the event from bubbling.

See example below: you'll notice that when you click the button, you only see the console log of "button clicked", and not "row clicked." This is because the `stopPropagation` prevented the click event for the `tr` from firing.

```js
$('tr').on('click', function(e){
  console.log('row clicked');
});

$('.delete').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('button clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> my row </td>
    <td> <button class='delete'>delete</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Edit: @skapicic's solution of using a data attribute is IMHO a better way of doing it, but if you really want to use an inline event handler, you can do a stopPropagation like this:

```
$content .= '<td><button onclick="event.stopPropagation(); deleteRecord('.$val->id.')"></td>';
```

[see this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387750/1233305)

Comment: is it possible to use it in this way onclick="deleteRecord(id);" function deleteRecord( what to get here ){ what.stopPropagation }

Comment: Yes, it's possible...see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: thanks @David784 that was helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You need the event that has been triggered and you need to [stop its propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: how to use it with onclick="deleteRecord(id);" function deleteRecord( what to get here ){  what.stopPropagation }

Comment: try refactoring the line to be
`$content .= '<td><button data-id="$val->id" onclick="deleteRecord"></td>';`
and in deleteRecord
`function deleteRecord(event){
event.stopPropagation();
var id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
...
}`

Comment: thanks skapicic this is good suggestion