# Move to tab but don't reload

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below with `window.open` to open a new link (same origin) in a new tab. If a tab with the new link is already open, the open tab should be focused instead.

This is all working fine, the focused tab is however always refreshed when it gains focus by this. How can I stop the focused tab from refreshing?

```js
window.open(`./${_id}`, `module_${_id}`);
```

Comment: Stop propagation? This may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: Which event will be created by this and how can I intercept it?

Comment: Most likely, the event is not created by this, but this is called by some event. Isn't it? (probably click)

Answer (score 2):

Check if the window is closed orelse use focus(), this should not refresh the page.

```
    var windowObject = null; // global variable
    
        function openURL(url) {
          if(windowObject == null || windowObject.closed) {
            windowObject= window.open(url);
          } else {
            windowObject.focus();
          }
        }

<button value="Check" onClick="openURL('https://www.google.com')"></button>
```

Comment: I see this working if it is always the same tab who opens the new tabs. But when opening the link from a third tab, it will still open the link in a new tab.

Comment: @Alrick Unless you are running this in a browser extension you have no way to check other tabs from inside a single page window. You might be able to use PostMessage API to communicate between windows you control